# how to control cars speed using anylogic

Tags: anylogic

i have to simulate a traffic on a highway using anylogic 8 learning edition, what I want to do is the control the car speed on road basis for ex if my car move from road1 to road 2 thru CarMoveTo I want to change the speed when it enters the road2... I tried to use "on enter" and "on exit" of the CarMoveTo but with no success and I even tried to use the Car API with no success too. I think I missed where is the suitable location to write the following code:

```
if (getRoad().equals("Road2"))
setPreferredSpeed(0, MPH);
```

Any Help?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think your getRoad().equals( "Road2" ) may be problematic.  getRoad returns a road object according to intelliSense, not a string.  Try taking out your quotation marks.

To set the speed at a certain road, try one of the following:
1) Use a stop line and on crossing the line, call your code to set the speed.  No need to figure out what road you are on, because the stop line will inherently be on the road of interest.
2) Use a road network descriptor, and call your code "On Enter Road"

If move to only applies to road2, you could also set it there.  However, if your move to block gives the car an overall destination that just happens to go through road2, then this would not be the right place, as it would get called just the first time the car enters the move to block.